Using Keypoint Feature Matching + Homography to Straighten Images: Only Works with Specific Cropped Template
I'm currently testing a method to straighten images using keypoint feature matching and homography. The goal is to align a query image to a template image. However, my current implementation only works when the template is cropped from the same specific image used for testing. If the query image is not that specific image, the code fails to align correctly.
Here is the code I'm using:
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def show_image(img, title=""):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title(title)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

def straighten_image(ORIG_IMG, IMG2):
    # Read both the images in color
    orig_image = cv2.imread(ORIG_IMG)
    img_input = cv2.imread(IMG2)
    
    orig_gray_scale = cv2.cvtColor(orig_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_scale_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_input, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Detect ORB features and compute descriptors
    MAX_NUM_FEATURES = 100
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_NUM_FEATURES)
    keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(orig_gray_scale, None)
    keypoints2, descriptors2= orb.detectAndCompute(gray_scale_img, None)
    
    # Match features
    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
    matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None)
    
    # Sort matches by distance
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
    
    # Remove not-so-good matches
    numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * 0.1)
    matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]
    
    # Draw top matches
    im_matches = cv2.drawMatches(orig_image, keypoints1, img_input, keypoints2, matches, None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
    show_image(im_matches, "Top Matches")
    
    # Homography
    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    
    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt
        
    # Find homography
    h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points2, points1, cv2.RANSAC)
    
    # Warp image
    height, width, channels = orig_image.shape
    inp_reg = cv2.warpPerspective(img_input, h, (width, height), borderValue=255)
    
    return inp_reg

template = "query_img2.jpg"
test = "container_2.JPG"

str_img = straighten_image(template, test)

show_image(str_img, "Aligned Image")

Working Example:
working aligned image
Not Working Example:
not working aligned image
Question:
How can I improve my code so that it works for any query image, not just ones cropped from the specific template? I want to handle cases where the query image might be similar but not an exact crop of the template. Any suggestions on preprocessing steps, feature matching improvements, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

pictures don't match. that's why feature matching fails. you'll need to involve machine learning.

Did you try to get just the four corners of the object instead of using detailed feature detection? If you you have the four corners it should be easy to warp the image accorindingly.

yes, (construct and) train some neural network model to infer the corners or directly infer the homography matrix. then you can unwarp the picture.
